# Assembler Directives without a dot

Tags: masm32

I recently started to learn MASM and was wondering why some of the Assembler Directives (like OPTION or include) don't start with a dot. Does the dot have a specific meaning or is that just due to inconsitent naming conventions?

Thanks in advance,
CloseButABanana

Comment: In some cases the initial period is used to distinguish between compile-time constructs and runtime constructs. For example `IF` lets you do conditional _assembly_ while `.IF` lets you do conditional _execution_. In others it's just a necessity, e.g. the directive `.486` vs the numeric constant `486`. And in some cases it's unclear why they chose one over the other, and conventions may have changed over time (e.g. `DOSSEG` and `.DOSSEG` both exist, with the same meaning).

Comment: Thank you very much! This question sounds so dumb, but I couldn't really find anything about it on the Internet. Very useful information.